# Detect the FTS3 extension in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, pysqlite, fts3

What is the SQLite query to detect if the FTS3 extension module is installed? Or is it possible to get a list of installed extensions with an SQLite3 query? It has to work with *pysqlite2*.

I know that I can get the list of tables using `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master`, I'd like to get something similar for the list of extensions. I also know that `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE v USING FTS3 (t TEXT)` succeeds iff FTS3 is installed, but I'd like to get a query without side effects (not even creating a temporary table).

As a workaround I have opened the `":memory:"` database, and issued the `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` command above.

Comment: Don't you have it the other way around? Is SQLite itself aware that it has an extension module? Just a thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it in SQLite at the moment; it forgets what it has loaded and cannot report it even if it wanted to (I checked the [source](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/src/loadext.c&v=1.60) to the code that does the loading, and the critical information that describes what is loaded is just not stored). It is [known](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions) (see **Wish List** at the bottom of that page) that it would be good to retain this information, but it does not appear to be retained as yet.

As a consequence, the only thing you can do is your current workaround – trying it and seeing if it works. Sorry I can't offer anything else.