# Sqlite3: Checking if database is FTS enabled?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm having trouble locating how to find out if my sqlite3 db is fts (four preferably) enabled.

I'm having trouble using the `MATCH` command, and I'm guessing it's because the db doesn't have FTS capabilities.

Google mostly returns mysql info about this.

Comment: The news is not good, though it may have changed in 5 years.... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482868/2836621

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could call the [sqlite3_compileoption_get() C function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/compileoption_get.html), or look at the output of [PRAGMA compile_options](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options) or the [sqlite_compileoption_get() SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#sqlite_compileoption_get):

```
WITH opts(n, opt) AS (
  VALUES(0, NULL)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1,
         sqlite_compileoption_get(n)
  FROM opts
  WHERE sqlite_compileoption_get(n) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT opt
FROM opts
WHERE opt LIKE '%FTS%';

ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS4
```

This [does not work for dynamically loaded extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553211/11654), though.

Comment: Good answer! Can you clarify if sqlite supports *dynamic* linked extensions and if this method would still detect FTS if deployed that way, if it does?